# How do I deserialize this JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code to deserialize this json but i keep getting this error:

> "Cannot convert object of type System.String to type
>   Namespace.Models.Url"

. The json structure is as below:

> [ { fileUrl: "localhost/ContentManager/get/ovYWB0/81/wallpaper" }, {
>   fileUrl: "localhost/ContentManager/get/AcjwO0/81/wallpaper" }, {
>   fileUrl: "localhost/ContentManager/get/HCR0q0/81/wallpaper" }
>    ]

The class i am mapping to is as below:

> ```
> public class Url
> {
>     public string FileUrl { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Response
> {
>     public Url FileUrl { get; set; }
> }
> ```

The deserializing code is as below:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
IList<MTContribute> data = new List<MTContribute>();

var items = serializer.Deserialize<List<Response>>(json);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var newData = new MTContribute
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Today,
        IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean("True"),
        MTContributeCategoryId = Category.MTContributeCategoryId,
        Url = item.FileUrl.FileUrl
    };

    data.Add(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your current json structure this should work

```
var items = serializer.Deserialize<List<Url>>(json); // Url instead of Response
```

if this won't work for you, you have to change the json structure in order to reflect the structure of `Response` class.

Unless I missed something, this is the necessary json structure

```
[{ fileUrl:{ fileUrl: "localhost/ContentManager/get/ovYWB0/81/wallpaper" }}]
```